# Cocoapods timeout issue

Tags: ios, github, timeout, cocoapods

I've been using cocoapods for a while now and never had any issues but since yesterday I've been getting timeouts from GitHub whey trying to execute `pod install`.

Here's my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'iCarousel'
pod 'SwipeView'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'
pod 'WYPopoverController'
pod 'MarqueeLabel'
pod 'MZFormSheetController'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh'
pod 'ReflectionView'
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu'
pod 'MONActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'HexColors'
pod 'ICViewPager'
pod 'SlackTextViewController'
pod 'STTweetLabel'
```

When I try to run `pod install` I get this message:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.5.0)

[!] Error installing AFNetworking
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git /Users/georgichristov/Documents/Workspace/Examples/IOS/DigiGraff-IOS/Pods/AFNetworking --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.5.0

Cloning into '/Users/georgichristov/Documents/Workspace/Examples/IOS/DigiGraff-IOS/Pods/AFNetworking'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Sometimes it manages to install more than one pod but fails to install all of them, thus making my project basically unusable. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that GitHub has been hit by a DDoS attack last thursday which is probably the reason for the timeouts.

http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/03/30/github-may-have-been-targeted-by-chinese-hackers-in-ddos-attack/